# Constantly spinning circle on startup

Tags: windows-10, start-screen

Have win10, had it for a while now on this machine. Had to move, computer spent a couple nights in my car at close to zero and now it won't boot.

Windows splash screen comes up fine. When that passes I get an eternal spinning circle and can't get it to stop.

I've tried shift+f8 and just f8 and both cause a blank black screen.

As a note, it won't boot past that at all, so I can't adjust settings in it at all.

At the moment I have two ideas for fixing it. Replacing the powerplant, I was having issues with it before this happened anyway so I think the cold just killed it's functionality, and using my disc to repair my install, but that has to wait till later.

Do either of those sound like viable fixes for this or?

Comment: Why would you leave a electronic device to those elements?  Moisture kills electronics.  Freezing temperatures kills electronics.  Extreme heat kills electronics.

Comment: @ramhound had no choice. Had 24 hours to get out and nowhere good to store.

Comment: @Ramhound actually freezing is good - thawing to allow dew and moisture is bad.